# Getting ETIMEDOUT error connecting to AWS MySQL DB from Heroku

Tags: mysql, node.js, heroku

So I have followed all the steps described here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/amazon_rds

When I run the `heroku config` command, I get:

```
DATABASE_URL: mysql2://[username]:[password]@hostname...
```

So I have added the configuration along with certificate in the ./config folder

When I try to login, the connection times out and this is what is in the log:

```
2014-01-25T16:26:59.037529+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 44600
2014-01-25T16:29:18.687464+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by jason.mogera@outlook.com
2014-01-25T16:29:18.735263+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v11 created by jason.mogera@outlook.com
2014-01-25T16:29:18.882191+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2014-01-25T16:29:21.439095+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2014-01-25T16:29:22.778653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2014-01-25T16:29:22.935805+00:00 app[web.1]: connect.multipart() will be removed in connect 3.0
2014-01-25T16:29:22.936445+00:00 app[web.1]: visit https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 for alternatives
2014-01-25T16:29:22.936779+00:00 app[web.1]: connect.limit() will be removed in connect 3.0
2014-01-25T16:29:23.064077+00:00 app[web.1]: Express server listening on port 23430
2014-01-25T16:29:24.833326+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2014-01-25T16:29:23.396737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-01-25T16:30:14.740476+00:00 app[web.1]: [90mPOST /login [32m200 [90m29992ms[0m
2014-01-25T16:30:14.736443+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path=/login host=www.novalist.co request_id=8ddc9973-03e4-4019-b47f-5da2efd84099 fwd="100.2.120.12" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
2014-01-25T16:30:59.002003+00:00 app[web.1]: [90mGET /login [32m200 [90m1016ms - 687b[0m
2014-01-25T16:30:59.007349+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/login host=www.novalist.co request_id=bd43af72-53c6-4507-8e2c-ad3e318e36f4 fwd="100.2.120.12" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=1028ms status=200 bytes=687
2014-01-25T16:30:59.445343+00:00 app[web.1]: [90mGET /stylesheets/index-foundation.css [36m304 [90m9ms[0m
2014-01-25T16:30:59.457731+00:00 app[web.1]: [90mGET /stylesheets/style.css [32m200 [90m244ms - 1.07kb[0m
2014-01-25T16:30:59.466690+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stylesheets/style.css host=www.novalist.co request_id=c21b445c-941d-4cbb-ab68-a71fab00e24c fwd="100.2.120.12" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=254ms status=200 bytes=1098
2014-01-25T16:31:35.144892+00:00 app[web.1]: [90mPOST /login [32m200 [90m29998ms[0m
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol._enqueue (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:110:26)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Protocol.handshake (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:42:41)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Connection.connect (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:81:18)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Strategy.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport-local/lib/passport-local/strategy.js:89:10)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at pass (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:145:5)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Strategy.module.exports [as _verify] (/app/auth.js:16:14)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Passport.authenticate (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:244:7)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     --------------------
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078494+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at callbacks (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:164:37)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at param (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:138:11)
2014-01-25T16:31:52.078720+00:00 app[web.1]:     at attempt (/app/node_modules/passport/lib/passport/middleware/authenticate.js:243:16)
2014-01-25T16:31:53.691098+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 8
2014-01-25T16:31:53.707160+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Answer (score 4):

Your rds port / host is not accessible from heroku. Change database [security group](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home?#s=SecurityGroups) and allow heroku ip to connect tcp/3306

Also note that node-mysql does [not yet](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/481) support ssl connections. If you need to connect to rds securely you may want to use [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2) or [node-mariasql](https://github.com/mscdex/node-mariasql)

Comment: oh thanks for the heads up on the node-mysql2. I will def switch. As far as the security group, how do you determine heroku ip. If found this article: http://blog.katworksgames.com/2012/08/19/connecting-your-heroku-app-with-its-mysql-database/ but when I go to add a new security group. It is not an option, and I can't add a new EC2 Security Group. Do you have any resources that can point to your suggestion?

Comment: Allow all IPs for the beginning - does this solve connection problem?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with this but I found the ip address of the heroku app. "ping appname.herokuapp.com" and took that IP and added it to security group like so CIDR/IP: {ipaddress}/32. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, use `{ipaddress}/32` in source field and `3306` in port range

Comment: that doesn't seem to work.. and tried to "ping" again and this time the ip address is different then before. Since the IPAddress is changing all the time what should be provided for {ipaddress}?

Comment: try to open access to all addresses temorarily to see if that helps - 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: according to this article you need the x-forwarded-for ip: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2013/12/04/getting-the-real-client-ip-address-on-a-heroku-hosted-nodejs-app/. However I grabbed the ip from the log and that doesn't work either.